# Status of RavenDB for mono / core

Tags: c#, mono, ravendb, .net-core

What's the current status of RavenDB working on mono and .NET Core? I've found [this](https://ayende.com/blog/174209/ravendb-4-0-on-dotnetcore-rc2), but it's a little out of date and the github repo doesn't appear to details specificially for core / mono.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.5 client is working on .NET core.

We are going to have a preview release for 4.0 in the next week or so that will have both server & client working on .NET core & linux.